# Is it safe to use launchIn(viewModelScope) within a viewModelScope.launch block in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a piece of Kotlin code in my Android application where I'm using coroutines and the ViewModelScope. I want to confirm if using launchIn(viewModelScope) within a viewModelScope.launch block might cause any issues or is considered a standard practice. Here's the code snippet for reference:

```
    fun test() {
      testJob?.cancel()

      testJob = viewModelScope.launch {
          delay(1000L)
          flow<String> {
              //
          }.onEach { 
              //
          }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you do it instead of just calling `collect()` though? You launch new job that executes the flow but it's not related to your `testJob` so you have no control over its cancellation.

Answer (score 2):

It's safe, but an unusual thing to want to do. By launching it directly in the scope, the collection becomes a new sibling coroutine instead of a child coroutine or just part of the current coroutine itself.

This would usually be more sensible:

```
fun test() {
    testJob?.cancel()

    testJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        delay(1000L)
        flow<String> {
            //
        }.collect { 
            //
        }
    }
}
```

But one possible reason I can think of you might want to do it your way would be if you wanted to be doing other stuff after starting collection and without waiting for it.